# Oracle SQL - How to divide a count by the sum of a count?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum, divide

I have a query that currently looks like this (simplified)

```
 SELECT
       m.academicyr,
       m.ncyeargrp_format AS YEAR,
       Count(*) AS cohort,
       round (Avg (m.per_att),4) AS attendance,
       Round (per_cohort,4)      

   FROM
 (
   SELECT
         s.academy,
         s.academicyr,
         s.adno,
         s.ncyeargrp_format,
         CASE WHEN a.possible_att_marks = 0 THEN NULL
           ELSE (a.present_att_marks / a.possible_att_marks)
             END
               AS per_att,
         a.possible_att_marks,
         a.present_att_marks,
         a.period,
         Count (*) AS cohort,
         Count (*) / Sum(Count(*)) AS per_cohort

   FROM
      VACADEMY_STU_all  s

   LEFT JOIN
        vacademy_attendance a
       ON s.academy = a.academy
      AND s.adno = a.adno
      AND s.term = a.period
      AND s.academicyr = a.academicyr

   WHERE
          s.academy = 'CAN'
          AND s.academicyr = '1617'
          AND a.period = '1'

          GROUP BY
         s.academy,
         s.academicyr,
         s.adno,
         s.ncyeargrp_format,
         a.possible_att_marks,
         a.present_att_marks,
         a.period

  ) m
          GROUP BY
          m.academicyr,
          m.ncyeargrp_format,
          m.per_cohort

          ORDER BY
          To_Number(Trim(regexp_replace(m.ncyeargrp_format, '[A-Za-z]')))
```

I am trying here to divide the count * by the sum of the count *. I am getting an error 'not a single group function'.

The query works perfectly fine without the 'Round (Per_cohort,4)' in the first select and also removed from the inner select and group by.

The outcome I am expecting is

Year Group  Stud Count  % of Cohort Ave Att
Year 7        126         18.18%    98.10%
Year 8        139         20.06%    93.88%
Year 9        143         20.63%    90.56%
Year 10       143         20.63%    95.94%
Year 11       142         20.49%    88.45%
Grand Total   693         100.00%   93.28%

I have all of the other columns working perfectly, I just need to percentage cohort, so the value in the cohort column divided by the total of the cohort column, which has been created using count *.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, I couldn't figure out how to change it.

Comment: When you edit, mark the code and click `{}`.

Comment: You simply need to group by the same values you want in select list; so, if you need to extract a rounded value, group by the rounded value

Comment: well change Round (per_cohort,4) to Round (sum(per_cohort),4) in your outer select.

Comment: You aren't grouping that case

Comment: @Prathyush: this seems different from what the OP needs, given that the query is aggregated by  per_cohort

Comment: With `COUNT(*)` you get the number of records per group, which is just one value, e.g. 10, for a group. With `SUM(COUNT(*))` you'd get the sum of this value (which is of course the value itself) if that were possible. So what do you actually want to achieve? It would be great if you could show some sample data and expected results. Your query seems overly complicated somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I have edited to show what I am looking to see.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the line that is getting the error:

```
     Count (*) / Sum(Count(*)) AS per_cohort
```

Then you can fix this by using window functions:

```
     Count (*) / Sum(Count(*)) over () AS per_cohort
```

Comment: I tried using this, but unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT s.academy,
           s.academicyr,
           s.adno,
           s.ncyeargrp_format,
           CASE WHEN a.possible_att_marks = 0 THEN NULL
                ELSE (a.present_att_marks / a.possible_att_marks)
           END AS per_att,
           a.possible_att_marks,
           a.present_att_marks,
           a.period,
           COUNT(*) AS cohort
    FROM VACADEMY_STU_all s
    LEFT JOIN vacademy_attendance a
        ON s.academy = a.academy AND
           s.adno = a.adno AND
           s.term = a.period AND
           s.academicyr = a.academicyr
    WHERE s.academy = 'CAN' AND
          s.academicyr = '1617' AND
          a.period = '1'
    GROUP BY s.academy,
             s.academicyr,
             s.adno,
             s.ncyeargrp_format,
             a.possible_att_marks,
             a.present_att_marks,
             a.period
)

SELECT m.academicyr,
       m.ncyeargrp_format AS YEAR,
       m.cohort,
       ROUND(AVG(m.per_att), 4) AS attendance,
       ROUND(m.cohort / (SELECT SUM(cohort) FROM cte), 4)
FROM cte m
GROUP BY m.academicyr,
         m.ncyeargrp_format,
         m.per_cohort
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(m.ncyeargrp_format, '[A-Za-z]')))
```

Comment: FROM (
   WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT
         s.academy,
         s.academicyr,
         s.adno,
         s.ncyeargrp_format,
         CASE WHEN a.possible_att_marks = 0 THEN NULL
           ELSE (a.present_att_marks / a.possible_att_marks)
             END
               AS per_att,
         a.possible_att_marks,
         a.present_att_marks,
         a.period,
         Count (*) / Sum(Count(*)) OVER () AS per_cohort
      )
      SELECT cte.cohort / (SELECT Sum(cohort) FROM cte)

Comment: I tried putting above what I have done, but the formatting is aweful, sorry. Anyway it's not working as I don't think I have put it in the right place.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the full query I have in mind.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. This isn't the full query though as it is a nested query. I have this in front of it, which is causing it to fail.

Comment: SELECT
       m.academicyr,
       m.ncyeargrp_format AS YEAR,
       Count(*) AS cohort,
       round (Avg (m.per_att),4) AS attendance,
       m.period,
       Round (m.per_cohort,4)

   FROM
 (